# Running a Batch with Admin Rights, but with pre saved User&Pass in the Batch to avoid windows asking for the Cridentials

Tags: batch-file, jar, admin-rights

I am already using the following Batch to open my Jar file with Admin Right:

```
@echo off
:: BatchGotAdmin (Run as Admin code starts)
REM --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
echo Requesting administrative privileges...
goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )
:UACPrompt
echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
"%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
exit /B
:gotAdmin
if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
pushd "%CD%"
CD /D "%~dp0"
:: BatchGotAdmin (Run as Admin code ends)
:: Your codes should start from the following line
-cp Jarfile.jar com.testApp
```

however after clicking on the Batch file, the windows will ask me to insert the Username and password.
The Question is , is there any way to give the user and pass inside the Batch file to open the Jar file but without windows asking for user and pass?

Comment: but i want to open the jar file with dmin rights, because some functions in the jar file need admin rights....

Comment: but i do not want to start it with schedule task ... I just want t click on it and open it and bypass the admin Rights or give the admin Rights user pass inside the Batch file but not myselfe in the windows